# Variables declared in the global scope - why are they equivalent to properties on the global obejct?

Tags: javascript, variables

In JavaScript why are variables declared in the global scope equivalent to properties on the global obejct?

Comment: Because the spec says so? Because of a mistake in the language design? What do you want to hear?

Comment: Variable declarations are processed before any code is executed. The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global. Source MDN(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the assignment is executed. The differences between declared and undeclared variables are:

Comment: Lol. I just thought there might be a reason...

Comment: Why are implicitlty undeclared variables considered global ?

Comment: Because of a mistake in the language design? :) lol